# Type 'FormArray' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'FormArray'. in angular6 typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6

How to solve the below-mentioned Error:

> Type 'FormArray' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.   Property
>   'includes' is missing in type 'FormArray'.
>   in line " this.items = this.AddUserstep2Form.get('items') as FormArray;"

I have the below-mentioned ts file. Please help me.

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators ,FormArray} from '@angular/forms';

 AddUserstep2Form: FormGroup;   items: any[] = [];

 ngOnInit() {
    this.AddUserstep2Form = this.fb.group({

      stateCode: ['',Validators.required],
      cityId:['',Validators.required],
      items: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ])

    })

createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      stateCode: '',
      cityId: ''
    });
  }
  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.AddUserstep2Form.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the `items` property on component, simply replace its current type with `FormArray`:

```
items: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
```

If you don't use it anywhere besides `addItem` method, then you can completely remove it from component and change `addItem` to this:

```
addItem(): void {
    const items = this.AddUserstep2Form.get('items') as FormArray;
    items.push(this.createItem());
}
```